# Cannot connect to MYSQL in a LAMP docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, lamp

I have a LAMP container. I want to run WordPress, but it cannot connect to Mysql.
I set the container port mapping to 3307:3306 because another container use the default mysql port. I tried to connect from host to the container's mysql server to test it, `mysql -u xxxx -h 127.0.0.1:3307` but the result is:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3307' (0)
```

I tried to change the bind address 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in the container's mysql config but nothing changed.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Please share the docker run command you have used to start mysql & the output of `netstat  -anp | grep LISTEN | grep 3307`

Comment: It works! I made some mistakes.

Comment: First, >mysql syntax wasn't correct. The correct syntax is: mysql -u xxxx -h  127.0.0.1 -P3307
Second, I didn't configure the mysql user to connect from another host.
The dockerized mysql functioned well from the first moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link database container to wordpress container. I do not know what do you use for containers and how you orchestrate them, but in the simplest case you have to add something like this:

```
--link some_mysql_container:mysql
```

when you are trying to run wordpress container. Of course first you need to create a database container. Let it has "some-mysql-for-wordpress" name (image mysql:latest). When you will have this, now you can run a wordpress container:

```
docker run --name some-wordpress --link some-mysql-for-wordpress:mysql -d wordpress
```

And that is all. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in php file, you can just use your container instead of host name.

```
function connect_db() {
   $dbhost = "database"; // <= like this
   $dbuser = "docker";
   $dbpass = "docker";
   $dbname = "dbname";
   $database_class = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
   $database_class->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   return $database_class;
}
```

this work for me. hope this help for other later 5 years.